# Difficulty finding point A using two equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have been having difficulty answering the following question:

The figure below shows a distribution between the
origin, O, and the point B. The section from O to A is represented by
the equation
$y = x^2$, whilst the section from point A to point B is
represented by the equation $3y = −20+ 20x −2x^2$. Find the coordinates
of the point A.[image]

Any help in terms of how to apply the correct methodology for this question and how to solve it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The point A satisfies both equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ A=(x_0,y_0) $. A is the intersection point between the two curves, which means that $ y_0 = x_0^2 $ and that $ y_0 = \frac{1}{3} \big( -20 + 20x_0 - 2x_0^2 \big) $.

Let $ y_0 = y_0 $, i.e.

$$ x_0^2 = \frac{1}{3} \big( -20 + 20x - 2x^2 \big) $$

$$ 3x_0^2 = -20 + 20x_0 - 2x_0^2 $$

$$ 5x_0^2 - 20x_0 + 20 = 0 $$

$$ 5 (x_0^2 - 4x_0 + 4) = 0 $$

$$ 5(x_0-2)(x_0-2) = 0 $$

$$ x_0 = 2 $$

Plugging this into either of the two equations, you get: $ y_0 = x_0^2 = (2)^2 = 4 $. Therefore, $ A=(x_0,y_0) = (2,4). $

Comment: just check  $x_0$ it should be $2$

Comment: @Karl you're right, thanks! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thankyou this makes lots of sense, Did not realise it was simple algebraic manipulation, it looked to me like a vectors question

Answer (score 1):

Plugging $y=x^2$ in the second equation, we get after simplification

$$x^2-4x+4=0$$ which gives the coordinates of the point $A :  x=2$ and
$y=4$.